# Why having two different version of php?

Tags: php, command-line, laravel-4, wampserver

My wamp server keeps telling me that i have php 5.4.12 installed but in a command line whenever is run php -v it says i have php version 5.3.24  . How could that be possible am running two different types of php versions?
As a result of having a lower version of php, i can't seed the laravel database. Please help

Comment: you can run 10 versions if you wanted to

Comment: Ask the administrator about the path to the correct php 5.4 binary

Comment: it's a local computer. I need to know what to do so that i can point to the latest version @zerkms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it! I checked the path to the php.exe in the command line by typing : C:>where php.exe and i was shocked to see i had IIS also installed in my computer. That IIS is the one having php v5.3 and as long as it's a microsoft product, it's given first priority hence i got php v 5.3 as default

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the wamp icon 
go to wamp> php> version>

you should see two versions select the one you want